# Function in one branch always runs when use Observable.if

Tags: javascript, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am using `Observable.if` to determine which action should be dispatched.

The code below, since it is `true`, so only `ACTION1` is dispatched, which is correct.

However, I found that `myFunction()` is also running which I didn't expect.

Any explanation will be great. Thanks

```
myFunction() {
  console.log('I did not expect this run');
  return 1;
}

export const myEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType('ACTION')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.if(
        () => true,
        Observable.of({ type: 'ACTION1' }),
        Observable.of({ type: 'ACTION2', payload: myFunction() })
      ));
```

Comment: Wrap it in an `Observable.defer`. Without the `defer`, it has to be invoked when the value is passed to `Observable.of` when the `Observable.if` is composed. `Observable.defer(() => Observable.of({ type: 'ACTION2', payload: myFunction() }))`

Comment: Wow, it works, please add it in answer so I can accept, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `myFunction` needs to be evaluated when the argument is passed to `Observable.of` and the result of `Observable.of` is passed to `Observable.if` as an argument, so it's evaluated when `Observable.if` is called - not when `Observable.if` receives a `next` notification.

To solve the problem, wrap it in an [`Observable.defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) call:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/defer';
// ...
export const myEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType('ACTION')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.if(
        () => true,
        Observable.of({ type: 'ACTION1' }),
        Observable.defer(() => Observable.of({ type: 'ACTION2', payload: myFunction() }))
      ));
```

The call to `Observable.of` (and thus the call to `myFunction`) will then be deferred until `Observable.if` receives a `next` notification.